# How to initialize string property from other arguments in Python class?

Tags: python, class

I am trying two join to Class args together to make another one.  The code below outputs the `Name` property as a `tuple` instead of a string.

```
# Person
class Person(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self,
            Collection = 'People',
            Firstname = '',
            Lastname = '',
            Name = '',
            **kwargs):
        self.Collection = Collection
        self.Firstname = Firstname
        self.Lastname = Lastname
        self.Name = '%s %s' % (self.Firstname, self.Lastname),
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

p = Person(Firstname='Foo',Lastname='Bar')  ## tuple, not string

p.Name = ('Foo', 'Bar')
```

The reason I am trying to join the first and last names in the `__init__` as opposed to just a property is because the `__init__` is tied to an inherited `save_to_database` method.  I want the `Name` property to be save to the db, but as a string, NOT as a tuple.

Any clues would be fantastic!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Obviously `p.Name` will be a tuple, because you set it to a tuple.  Are you saying that you want to intercept that assignment so that `p.Name = ('foo', 'bar')` will actually assign a string to `p.Name` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma. Turn this...

```
self.Name = '%s %s' % (self.Firstname, self.Lastname),
```

into this:

```
self.Name = '%s %s' % (self.Firstname, self.Lastname)
```

(You're effectively doing `self.Name = 'foo',` instead of `self.Name = 'foo'`, and `'foo',` is a single-element tuple with the only element being a string, whereas `'foo'` is just a string.)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're explicitly setting p.Name to a tuple value after the constructor has run.    In particular, p.Name looses the formatting you gave it in the constructor when you run

```
p.Name = ("foo", "bar")
```

Right now your init function is nearly setting P.name correctly.  As Amber pointed out, you need to drop the comma on the self.Name = ... line.  If you fix this, and remove the last line of the code where you mutate the value of self.Name, I think it will do everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to:

1. keep attribute `Name` as a string,
2. on assigning new `Name`, set `Firstname` and `Lastname` and also save the change to db,

you should overload the `__setattr()__` method of the class.

Here's an example: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/389916-example-setattr-getattr-overloading/